# Scanner- trouble finding file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to load a text file into java, but I'm having trouble locating the file within my code. 
My file is named 'test.txt' and is saved under src/test.txt , src/fileIOTest/test.txt , and in a resources file, but regardless of how I try to load the file, the program can't seem to locate it. It shows up in the package explorer, but throws a file not found exception.

```
package fileIOTest;

 //This project tests out the scanner system, reading a text file into an array.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

public void init(){


    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("/test.txt"));
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();// print the error
    }

    int[] testArray = new int[10];  

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        testArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(testArray[i]);
        }

    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    Test fileLoader = new Test();
    fileLoader.init();

    }
}
```

Edit: Here's my file system  [image: Here's my file system]

Comment: remove the dash from ("/test.txt"))

Comment: No luck with that either.

Comment: He meant slash, and you should generally use `getResourceAsStream` for this kind of task anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try:

```
File directory = new File("src/test.txt");
Path file = Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath());
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Or: Try removing slash might work:

```
Scanner sc = newScanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));
```